# index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000

Tags: java

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

nP=1000 
ns=1001 

x=np.zeros([nM,nP]) 


for i in range(1,nM+1): 
for k in range(1,nP+1):  
    d=np.random.random()
    x[i,k]=x[i,k-1]+d
```

tying to make 1000 "person" walk in a random direction (north, south, east, west) each walking 1001 step. getting the error 
index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array's maximum index should be one less than the size. In this case, as the array size is 1000, the maximum value for the index should be 999(which will be referring to the 1000th element.)

If you need the 1001st element, ensure that you set the size of the array to 1001 and access it using index = 1000.